# Need to drop completely empty rows from concatenated dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am concatenating multiple html tables into a single dataframe. Unfortunately, one of the columns has a list of url links, so the Pandas 1.5 `read_html(extract_links='all')` doesn't work; it only grabbed the first link.

So I wrote a set of custom processing functions. `collect_dataframes` calls  `convert_html_to_dataframe` from a list comprehension to create a list of dataframes. The final concatenated dataframe from `collect_dataframes` winds up with an empty row between each set of rows. The origin of the empty row is in the HTML table.

```
def collect_dataframes(self):
    dfs = [self.convert_html_to_dataframe(file) for file in self.files]
    return pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

I need all of the completely empty rows dropped one way or the other. I'm currently dropping the row after a single table is converted to a dataframe in `convert_html_to_dataframe`. Is there a better way or place to do it at?

Also, could someone please explain why the second version of `convert_html_to_dataframe` doesn't work?

WORKS: drops the first row and returns dataframe

```
def convert_html_to_dataframe(self, file):
    with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        content = f.read()
    df = pd.DataFrame(self.parse_html_table(content))
    df.drop([0], inplace=True)
    return df
```

DOES NOT WORK: returns an empty dataframe

```
def convert_html_to_dataframe(self, file):
    with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        content = f.read()
    df = pd.DataFrame(self.parse_html_table(content))
    return df.drop([0], inplace=True)
```

Comment: In your second implementation, your function will return None because of `inplace=True` in the `df.drop`. When `inplace` is set to `True`, that method will return `None`, instead modifying the dataframe inplace.

Comment: Idk how your dfs lookn wish there was a reproducible example. but have you tried `df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')`

Comment: If I change version 2 to `return df.drop([0])` it works. I'm not sure how to conceptualize why `inplace` isn't working the way I thought it's supposed to, but at least I know what to read about. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Both responses worked on a table of concatenated dataframes, but I went with @Echo's response in the end since it was easier to remember later on: `df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')`